# Postgresql foreign data wrapper constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, foreign-data-wrapper, multicorn

I want to create a foreign table and add a column with a constraint. It would look something like this:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE test (
    id integer CHECK(id > 1),
    value character varying
) server test options (
    tablename 'test',
    db_url 'url',
    primary_key 'id'
);
```

It gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  constraints are not supported on foreign tables
LINE 2: id int CHECK (id > 1),
```

So apparently at the moment this is not possible. Is there any workaround for this? If not then will this work in the future at some point? I'm on PostgreSQL 9.3.3 using FDW plugin [Multicorn](http://multicorn.org/) and my foreign table is on MySQL database.

Comment: You'll have to enforce the constraint on the remote side for now. There's been discussion of supporting `check` constraints on foreign tables, but the problem is that Pg has no way to know if they're valid or to enforce them on the remote data. The planner makes assumptions based on check constraints that could cause it to generate an incorrect plan if the check constraint doesn't actually match the data in the foreign table. So for now, it's not supported.

Comment: @CraigRinger What about using user defined function to check the constraint manually? Wouldn't this be a good solution to this problem? Example: `CHECK (someFunction(field) IS TRUE)`